# Middle Item in Odd Numbered Array List

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop

can someone please explain how to solve this problem without using a return statement?

Given a sorted list of integers, output the middle integer. A negative number indicates the end of the input (the negative number is not a part of the sorted list). Assume the number of integers is always odd.

Ex: If the input is: 2 3 4 8 11 -1
the output is: Middle item: 4

The maximum number of list values for any test case should not exceed 9. If exceeded, output "Too many numbers".

Hint: First read the data into an array. Then, based on the array's size, find the middle item.

```
    import java.util.Scanner; 

    public class LabProgram {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
      Scanner scnr = new Scanner(System.in);
      int[] userValues = new int[10];     
      int arrayLength = 0;
      int i;
      int middleInteger;
      
      for (i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
          userValues[i] = scnr.nextInt();
      
         if (userValues[i] == -1) {
            arrayLength = i + 1;
            break;
         }
         
         if ((i == 9) && (userValues[i] != -1)) {
            System.out.println("Too many numbers");
            return;
         }
      }
      middleInteger = (arrayLength - 1) / 2;
      
      System.out.println("Middle item: " + userValues[middleInteger]);
    }
    }
```

Comment: What is the specific problem you have with your current implementation of this homework assignment?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***You can use conditional checks after you come out of the for loop to determine whether it's too many numbers or a valid middle number scenario.*** In that case, you can avoid using return statement explicitly and let the method exit after executing complete code. For example, you might consider doing something like this:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
      Scanner scnr = new Scanner(System.in);
      int[] userValues = new int[10];     
      int arrayLength = 0;
      int middleInteger;
      
      for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
          userValues[i] = scnr.nextInt();
         if (userValues[i] < 0 || i == 9) {
            arrayLength = i + 1;
            break;
         }
      }
      if(arrayLength==10 && userValues[arrayLength-1]>0)
        System.out.println("Too many numbers");
      else {
        middleInteger = (arrayLength) / 2 - 1;
        System.out.println("Middle item: " + userValues[middleInteger]);
      }
    }
```